# Making a private siyum before mass siyum hashas

Tags: siyum

If one joined a group to finsh shas,and chose a mashechta to finish and he finished the mashechta before the shas event. Can he make a private siyum before the event and still it will be counted towards the siyum hashas,Or is that double dipping?

Is the siyum hashas now considered chaser since that one person made a siyum already,and when they say the hadran on shas it really isnt true.

Comment: Is there any issue besides saying the kaddish? If he says kaddish on the whole shaas, can't it be he is including a masechta he has already said kaddish on? Why is this different than making individual siumim on every masechta?

Comment: He isnt making the siyum at the event,will add that in

Comment: @user6591 Saying Kaddish is not an issue. Anyone can say Kaddish after teaching any amount of Torah in public.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem making more than one siyum on the same Sha"s. When I was in Camp Massad many years ago, I am fairly certain that I led the same siyum twice during the 9 days. We had 2 different lunch shifts as the dining room wasn't large enough to contain all the campers & counselors at once.

Comment: @Double I was assuming the one saying kaddish would want to say the nusach for a siyum. That's why I phrased it like that. I know that most people do say the end of the masechta at a siyum, which would qualify for the kaddish dirabanan that you are focusing on. Is that a requirement though for the siyum nusach?

Comment: @user6591 Do you mean the inclusion of "lechadata alma"? There are no requirements for that AFAIK. It's customary in many circles to include it at funerals and/or yahrtzeit events. Some also add it at non-yahrtzeit Siyumim or just on days with Tachanun. Yemenites include it at every Kaddish Derabanan IINM. It's not a Halakha for anyone. When to say a Kaddish is Halakha.

Comment: Is this different than when the daf yomi groups make a little siyum on each masechta and then a big siyum on the whole thing?  I've seen this done plenty of times, particularly when they finish a masechta close to erev Pesach.

Comment: Same exact thing,I am asking if its allowed

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem would be. What is a "chaseir" siyum? What would be untrue in the Hadran?

Comment: Are you asking whether both count toward a _mitzva_ meal, to e.g. allow meat before 9 _Av_?